# Plotting two lists of different lengths versus each other

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have two data lists and would like to plot them versus each other.

```
list1 = Get["http://pastebin.com/raw/Y9FFBzV5"];
list2 = Get["http://pastebin.com/raw/UjWXjgEL"];
```

The problem is they are of different length:

```
Dimensions[list1]
{4882}

Dimensions[list2]
{1392}
```

I would like to "stretch" `list2` to the same length as `list1`, so that missing data should be interpolated.

UPDATE:

In the plot the minimum point should be `{list1[[1]],list2[[1]]}`. The maximum point should be (after data processing of `list2`): `{list1[[4882]],list2[[4882]]}`

What do I have to do?

Comment: `ListLinePlot[{list1, list2}, DataRange -> {0, 100}]`, see [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html)

Comment: @lio There are two issues here. Would you like to plot them at the same graph, or one against the other (in this case in what order). The second issue is your "stretching" therm. Do you want to extrapolate missing points (of vector 2) or add points in between existing points and interpolate them. Or in other words, do terminal points of `list1` correspond to terminal points of `list2`

Comment: @ercegovac: I want not make two curves, the lists shoudl be plotted against each other, `list1` as the horizontal axes and `list2` as vertical axis.

Comment: @lio You did not answer the second part of the question. Interpolation (adding points between existing points) or extrapolation beyond one of the terminal points.

Comment: `ListLinePlot[Thread[{list1, ArrayResample[list2, Length@list1]}]]`

Comment: @lio Seams you did not understand what i mean. There is more than one way to add more points to `list2`. One is `Interpolation` (see [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation)) and another one is `Extrapolation` (again, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation))

Comment: @ercegovac: sorry ... adding points into `list2` but keeping the range.

Comment: @JasonB. gave an answer for that.

Comment: @Jason B: Great, how can I vote for this solution as an answer?

Comment: @lio - sorry I'm being lazy and dumping an answer in the comments, not the best practice.  You could post it below and accept it

Answer (score 8):

Jason. B. has answered to my problem.

His solution is:

```
ListLinePlot[Thread[{list1, ArrayResample[list2, Length@list1]}], 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"list2", ""}, {"list1", ""}}]
```

[image]